# Local Apache web server works only when connected to the net

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, lamp

I installed Ubuntu and got the LAMP stack installed as well. The problem is I have to be connected to the internet for the local Apache webserver to work.

I changed the IP address on the dnshost, in the apache2.conf file, got the servername in the httpd.conf, which was empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you elaborate what "does not work" means exactly? Does it not start, does it simply not respond (what IPs/hostnames did you try)? Do any of the relevant error logs show anything noteworthy?

Comment: Its chrome that has an issue with ubuntu.  It says server not found when unplugged from network.

Comment: check your AllowOverride property in .htaccess ( change to All )

Answer (score 1):

Does the server actually *not run* or does your browser just complain when you visit `http://localhost` in offline mode? Especially Firefox has an annoying tendancy to think that `localhost` is a remote server and needs to be kicked out of offline mode in order to be willing to attempt a connection.

Comment: I use chrome, none of the browsers are offline though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer to:

[Why does Apache server only work if I have an Internet connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/185816/why-apache-server-works-only-if-i-have-internet-connection)